# HTML ImageLink is not showing up on ASP.NET MVC Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display the ImageLink on my ASP.NET MVC Page.

HTML.**ImageLink** is not showing up.

Did i miss any libraries?

Appreciate your response.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't an ImageLink extension in MVC proper.  You might find some ideas on these questions:

[ASP.NET MVC Ajax.ActionLink with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341649/asp-net-mvc-ajax-actionlink-with-image)
[Is there an ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelper for image links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675319/is-there-an-asp-net-mvc-htmlhelper-for-image-links)

or you could do something simple like:

```
<a href='<%= Url.Action( "action", "controller" ) %>'>
   <img src='<%= Url.Content( "~/content/images/img.png" ) %>' alt="Action" />
</a>
```