# Can we use Html.ActionLink() for url's outside the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.actionlink

I need to have links which will point to other website web pages. Currently I am using the following method.

```
<a href="@reseller.Url">Product-Page</a>
```

I was wondering if i can use ActionLink for the same. Or ActionLink is just for in-house action methods ? Do I have other better choices or my above usage is correct for the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActionLink` method is strictly for "Action Methods", which are methods in a controller that return an `ActionResult`.

**Your above usage is correct.**

If you wish to wrap the entire link creation process, you could create your own helper method on the `HtmlHelper` class to do this.

This answer shows an example of creating an HTML helper for image links:

[Is there an ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelper for image links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675319/is-there-an-asp-net-mvc-htmlhelper-for-image-links)

Yours would probably be simpler, if you do choose to write a helper.