# Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.String]' to type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to follow the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675319/is-there-an-asp-net-mvc-htmlhelper-for-image-links) Stack Overflow question regarding a custom Image Link helper. The code works, as long as I remove the `.MergeAttributes` command. When used, this command blows up, throwing the following exception

> Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'.

Below is the code from the helper class I'm using. The idea was to only use two string values as input parameters, and any other HTML/img tag attributes input as properties of the input objects.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ImageLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string imgSrc, string url, object imgAttributes, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        UrlHelper urlHelper = ((Controller)htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller).Url;
        var imgTag = new TagBuilder("img");
        imgTag.MergeAttribute("src", imgSrc);
        imgTag.MergeAttributes((IDictionary<string, string>)imgAttributes, true); //Exception thrown here

        var imgLink = new TagBuilder("a");
        imgLink.MergeAttribute("href", url);
        imgLink.InnerHtml = imgTag.ToString();
        imgLink.MergeAttributes((IDictionary<string, string>)htmlAttributes, true);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(imgLink.ToString());
    }
```

And here is the code from the Razor/.cshtml file.

```
@Html.ImageLink(Url.Content("~/Content/images/Screen.PNG"), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Periscope"], 
                               new {title="Search Periscope"} , new { target="_blank"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes()` method of `HtmlHelper` to cast your object. Replace the following lines

```
imgTag.MergeAttributes((IDictionary<string, string>)imgAttributes, true);
imgLink.MergeAttributes((IDictionary<string, string>)htmlAttributes, true);
```

with

```
imgTag.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(imgAttributes), true);
imgLink.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are casting is not seems valid.

use this following extension method to make it working.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ImageLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string imgSrc, string url, object imgAttributes, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        UrlHelper urlHelper = ((Controller)htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller).Url;
        var imgTag = new TagBuilder("img");
        imgTag.MergeAttribute("src", imgSrc);
        var color = imgAttributes.ToDictionary<string>();
        imgTag.MergeAttributes(color, true); //No moer Exception thrown here

        var imgLink = new TagBuilder("a");
        imgLink.MergeAttribute("href", url);
        imgLink.InnerHtml = imgTag.ToString();
        imgLink.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(imgLink.ToString());
    }
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object source)
    {
        return source.ToDictionary<object>();
    }

    public static IDictionary<string, T> ToDictionary<T>(this object source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            ThrowExceptionWhenSourceArgumentIsNull();

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, T>();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(source))
            AddPropertyToDictionary<T>(property, source, dictionary);
        return dictionary;
    }

    private static void AddPropertyToDictionary<T>(PropertyDescriptor property, object source, Dictionary<string, T> dictionary)
    {
        object value = property.GetValue(source);
        if (IsOfType<T>(value))
            dictionary.Add(property.Name, (T)value);
    }

    private static bool IsOfType<T>(object value)
    {
        return value is T;
    }

    private static void ThrowExceptionWhenSourceArgumentIsNull()
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source", "Unable to convert object to a dictionary. The source object is null.");
    }
```